What is this symbol?
overall schematic

symbol in question

This is the image from the balanced modulator circuit the Datasheet of MC1496. I mean the circle that is grounded , what is that?
it is connected to the pin 10 (carrier input) of the IC.

I've added the whole circuit

You used completely unrelated tags. [tag:modes] has a clear meaning in the context of amateur radio, this has nothing to do with SSB. And jargon means … well, jargon. Not "component names".

I believe that symbol shows a shielded connector with the shield connected to ground.

And the "15V" at the top of the inset is attached to the capacitor (i.e., it's a 25uF, 15V capacitor, probably electrolytic) and doesn't belong to the shielded cable.

Jim I just changed “connected” to “connector” because I think that’s what you intended but had a typo… If I’m off the mark, undo the edit!
